# Image control default image binding at XAML page when retrieve image url is empty

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Hi All
    At Silverlight 4.0 XAML page (not using code behind), I'm binding Source to Image control. I want to show default image when retrival ImageUrl (from Database) is null or empty.

I'm trying the TargetNullValue as following , but not showing default image when ImageUrl is null or empty

```
     <Image Grid.Column="0"
               x:Name="YourAvator"
               Width="100"
               Height="100"
               Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='../Images/default_avator.jpg'}"
               Stretch="Fill" />
```

Please advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it simply by using a converter:

```
Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=../Images/default_avator.jpg}"
```

In MyImageConverter you look at 'value', if it's null you return a new ImageSource with the URL received as ConverterParameter.